# how to user active_admin with best_in_place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

I want to make active_admin editable in place..

So I use gem best_in_place

However..I come into many problems..

1) I typed

```
$("document").ready ->
    $(".best_in_place").best_in_place()
```

in the application.js...but it seems active_admin has its own js system and does not include application.js at all...

I managed to solve it by change active_admin's config file by setting

```
config.register_javascript 'application.js'
```

However, I have to run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

whenever I make some change...

so is there a easy way to fix this problem?

2) Finally, I got javascript loaded..but...the stylesheet of best_in_place seems not work..for when I move mouse on some div, it ought to be styled but not...how to fix it?

3) Another serious problem..after I finishing editing some content, I press Enter..then an error occurs: saying

```
batch_action not found in Admin::MemberController
```

I think active_admin capture the 'Enter Press' event, for when I finished editing and click any blank place..the best_in_place works and the database changed..

so..how to fix it?

4) Last question...to update edited value immediately, I need to add such code into my controller:

```
respnd_to: :html, :json
def update
    @member = Member.params[:id]
    @member.update_attributes(params[:member])
    respond_with @member
end
```

within active_admin...where should I add those code?

I will be very appreciate if you can help me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with it throwing a batch_action not found. When I disabled all batch actions, best_in_place started working.